# how can be changed hot_standby parameter on postgres 9.6 aws/rds?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws, master-slave-replication

I have a postgres solution on aws/rds with a master and a read replica.

```
                         master    slave
hot_standby               on        on
transaction_read_only     on        on
pg_is_in_recovery()       true      true
```

Having the master set in this way the vacuum and analyze process don't work.
Any idea how to change this setting?
thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. You have set a master/slave and want to run vacuum and analyze on slave?
You don't need it a as vacuum and analyze action from the master are replicate to the slave...

Comment: I have a master and a read-only standby.
I need to run vacuum/analyze on master.

Comment: Ok, so I'm sorry, I hadn't understand correctly...

Comment: It seems, this master behaves as a slave. I don't understand how it was possible. From aws, the hot_standby parameter can't be modified.

I have an other db, master/slave, that have the following settings:

_________________________master____slave<br/>
hot_standby_______________off________on<br/>
transaction_read_only_______off________on<br/>
pg_is_in_recovery()_________false_______true<br/>

here, it's possible to execute vacuum/analyze.
also, autovacuum/autoanalyze processes run.

Comment: I don't know if the previous comment is clear

hot_standby = off 
transaction_read_only = off
pg_is_in_recovery()=false

Comment: You don't have a master.  You have two slaves, one of which you have given a misleading name.

Comment: on aws console I see, for the first db (master), the replication role being 'master', and for second db (slave) being 'replica'

Answer (score 1):

Ideally the parameter `hot_standby` should be `on` only for slave server and `pg_is_in_recovery()` should be `false` for master server.

You can follow below steps to make these changes:

1. Check **postgresql.conf** file on master server and if the parameter `hot_standby` is set to `on` you can change it to `off` and then restart the server.
2. On the master server in the data file location, if there is a file called **recovery.conf** then just delete that file and restart the server.

Hope this will help.

Comment: ..and is postgresql.conf available in RDS?